# Ubuntu 11.04 server adding desktop environment

Tags: apt, desktop-environments

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 Server.

I installed a Desktop environment to Ubuntu server for Graphical usage.
I installed ubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But it only works when I have an internet connection. Is it possible to have desktop environment without an internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,It is possible. Here I explain the way I usually do, since I have same situation.

Limit is that you `must have same architecture` of systems.

First Clean Cache using following command in terminal.

```
   sudo apt-get clean
```

Dwonload packages for Install Ubuntu desktop using this command

```
sudo apt-get install -d ubuntu-desktop
```

This command will download packages only.

Now go to `places`. Open  `Filesystem > var > Cache > apt> achieve`

You will get all downloaded packages here. Copy all to folder.

Copy that folder to Usb drive.

Now Insert usb that server you want to install ubuntu desktop.
Type following commands.

```
cd /media/<your USB drive>/<folder>
sudo dpkg -i <all .deb packages>.
```

This will install .deb packages in System. You can install any .deb packages in this way.

Comment: isnt it easier to just place it in the home folder, for mountable devices get renamed every time? Still nice answer though

Comment: You can also put in share folder if you are connected with network. I suggested to use pendrive if both servers are in not connected with network. And USB automatically mounts or if not mount you can check by ls.

Comment: This is very simple technique.

Comment: i couldn't find any folder called "apt" inside "var"

Comment: Sorry, Edited answer.

Comment: It doesn't works. Nothing downloaded in Filesystems/var/cahe/apt/achieves . Please do help

Comment: it works on every ubuntu.

Comment: there is only partial folder and lock file in var/cache/apt/archieves

Comment: Now  you should  run sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop -d  command it will download .deb packages there. You will find packages between lock file and archieves folder.

Comment: am not getting those things

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install -d ubuntu-desktop command.

Comment: i tried not yet getting the output.

Comment: In my server it works fine..